# Android Studios crash

Tags: java, android

Im new to Android Studios. Earlier I had all my buttons on the home scree working fine, but when I tried to run it there it is crashing.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.start.layout.*;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button startbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartButton);
    startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Start.class));
        }
    });
    Button historybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HistoryButton);
    historybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, History.class));
        }
    });
    Button settingsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SettingsButton);
    settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.mf124.pricetackbenj, PID: 2619 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead
```

Thats the code for my buttons. Its the start button that is crashing, the other two are working fine. 
Anyone see a reason why this wouldn't be working?

The errors are:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.example.mf124.pricetackbenj, PID: 1994
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
>
> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to
>   false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has
>   an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your
>   theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: post your error also

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.mf124.pricetackbenj, PID: 2619
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Answer (score 0):

include this line in your style.

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

I hope it will work.

Here is your style folder

[image]

Comment: I know this is going to sound really stupid and im sorry but this is the first time if done anything with android studio... But where is my style?

Comment: @Bjohnston see the picture. I added with my answer

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work Hitesh